# SQL Server MCSA Certification

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, learning

I want to take MCSA: Sql Server 2016 Database Administration certification. 
I checked this link :

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/mcsa-sql2016-database-administration-certification.aspx

It says, I have to attend 70-464 and 70-465 exams. Is there any other precondition? I couldn't find clear certification path.

PS: I never attend certifications exam before. This will be my first.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just looking at an old page. It even says that it is only being maintained for reference purposes only:

> This page is being retained for reference purposes only. The information on this page, including statements about upgrade and/or substitution options, is not being updated and may no longer be accurate.

For the certification track you wish to take use the link below instead:

[MCSA: SQL 2016 Database Administration](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/mcsa-sql2016-database-administration-certification.aspx)

In brief, you just need to pass your 70-764 and 70-765 to earn the MCSA: SQL 2016 Database Administration Certificate. No more, no less.

Comment: Is it possible to attend 70-764 and 70-765, without 70-761 and 70-762?

Comment: Yes, the 761 and 762 are for the Database Development Certification and are not directly related or needed to pass the 764 and 765.

Answer (score 1):

As per [MCSA: SQL 2016 Database Administration](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/mcsa-sql2016-database-administration-certification.aspx), before attempting [Exam 70-764](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-764.aspx) and [Exam 70-765](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-765.aspx), you have to possess foundational IT skills. If you feel that you do not possess these skills, consider pursuing one or more *Microsoft Technology Associate* (MTA) certifications.

For completion of MCSA: SQL 2016 Database Administration certification by passing the required exam is (Exam 70-764 :- Administering a SQL Database Infrastructure) & (Exam 70-765:- Provisioning SQL Databases). After completion of **both exams** you shall get MCSA: SQL 2016 Database Administration certification.

For separate specific details, please see [Exam 70-764](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-764.aspx) and [Exam 70-765](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-765.aspx).

For more information related to SQL Server exams, follow [Daniel Calbimonte's blog on MSSQLTips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4644/sql-server-exam-70761-study-material-for-querying-data-with-transactsql).